# Calculating angular rate

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, vector, angle

I'm simulating a physical object, using a mass spring system. By means of deltas and cross products, I can easily calulate the up, forward and side vectors.

I want to calculate what the angular rate (how fast it's spinning), for the object space X, Y and Z axis. Calculating the world space angle first won't help, since I need the angular rate in object space (how a sensor glued to the object would see it).

Any 3D maths people out there know how to do this?

Comment: How about: Transform everything from world space to object space, then calculate the angular rate. That seems simplistic, but does it fail in some way?

Comment: I think this is more closely related to physics than programming. Anyway, a drawing may help a lot.

Comment: @LarsH: or just transform the angular velocity vector...

Comment: Since it's a spring-mass model, I'm guessing you don't even have a transformation from object to world coordinates right?

Comment: I know what the objects X, Y and Z axis are in world space, so I could generate a matrix from it. I thought there might be an easy way if I have the current X,Y,Z axis, and the old ones.

Comment: You have an object rotating in 3D, and you want to calculate its rotation rates around the body-fixed axes. Is that correct? What information do you start with?

Comment: @Hannesh: May I recommend that you take some time to study the subject in a first year physics type context. Not that I mean to sound discouraging, but if it is not obvious to you that Jefromi's answer is correct (assuming of course that you have the time dependent coordinate transform available) then you are likely to get stuck *over and over again*. Avoiding repeated mistakes will pay for the lost time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to take the CG of all the masses. Average the velocities of all the masses (using a mass-weighted average) this is the velocity of the object. Then take the velocity of each mass minus the velocity of the CG and compute the angular velocity using this relative velocity and the position relative to the CG - I think that's a cross product. This will give you the angular velocity vector in world coordinates. This may be averaged for all the masses, since they will be slightly different as the springs allow deformation. Simply project this angular velocity vector onto the (world space) sensor axis via dot-product and you have your object-space angular velocity on that axis. Your sensor axis must be a unit vector, and you'll need 3 of them - which you say you can get.

Comment: Simple, yet smart. Thanks phkahler.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [Lagrange mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian) in order to describe the system dynamics.